# Need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, for-loop

I was writing the following code to create a dictionary:

```
for a,b,c in foo:
   d=float(a or 0)-float(b or 0)
   bar[c]=d
   print bar
```

This works but gives me bar over and over.
However when I try to use bar outside the for loop, i get the following error;

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: In `foo`, you have a `tuple` that contains only one value instead of three.

Comment: Share the code where you assign foo

Comment: Also share the code that actually raises the error, and the traceback that you get with the error. It's very hard to debug partial error information relating to code we can't see.

Answer (score 2):

That error message means you are trying to store one value in a tuple that requires more than one value.

```
>>>(x,y,z) = [5]
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

You should look for somewhere in your code where you are assigning to a tuple.  It seems that `foo` is a list of tuples.  Maybe you are trying to assign something to an element of `foo`